# Passing parameter from window bat to UNIX shell script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, unix

i know topic seems very familiar and there are many answers given for same, but my issue is something else.I have a **.bat** file in which i am passing more then **10 parameters**(I know limit is 9 but i need it).It seems to be working fine.Script is below-:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
   set vector[!n!]=%%a
   set /A n+=1
)

SET sadminUser=%vector[0]%
SET sadminPassword=%vector[1]%
SET dsnProvider=%vector[2]%
SET dbUserName=%vector[3]%
SET schemaFilePath=%vector[4]%
SET ddldictschemalogPath=%vector[5]%
SET repositoryName=%vector[6]%
SET ddlimpschemalogPath=%vector[7]%
SET grantUserRole=%vector[8]%
SET userId=anyuser
SET host=myhost
SET password=password
SET datatable=%vector[9]%
SET indexTable=%vector[10]%
SET ddlimpschemalogPath2=%vector[11]%

echo %ddlimpschemalogPath2%


echo y | "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink" -ssh %userId%@%host% -pw %password% exit

"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink" -ssh %userId%@%host% -pw %password% "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin /opt/siebel/w44gq8sw/DDL_Sync.sh %sadminUser% %sadminPassword% %dsnProvider% %dbUserName% %schemaFilePath% %ddldictschemalogPath% %repositoryName% %ddlimpschemalogPath% %grantUserRole% %datatable% %indexTable% %ddlimpschemalogPath2%"  > ddlSuccess.txt 2>&1
```

Now as you see i am doing **echo %ddlimpschemalogPath2%** which is last parameter in array,and i can see correct output as well.

Problem is when i try to pass these **parameters** into **UNIX Shell Script**.You can see i am doing in bat file using putty command line `Plink`.I can successfully connect to **shell script** as well,And i am trying to echo all the passed parameters in shell script.But facing some issue . Script is below-:

```
#!/bin/bash

sadminUser=$1
sadminPassword=$2
dsnProvider=$3
dbUserName=$4
schemaFilePath=$5
ddldictschemalogPath=$6
repositoryName=$7
ddlimpschemalogPath=$8
grantUserRole=$9
datatable=${10}
indexTable=${11}
ddlimpschemalogPath2=${12}


echo "$sadmimUser"
echo "$sadminPassword"
echo "$ddlimpschemalogPath2"

echo password | sudo -S -l
sudo host  << EOF

// Do something else
EOF
```

I Found one issue. In `.bat` i have parameter called -: `repositoryName` . When i do `echo %repositoryName%` it gives `"Siebel Repository"` correct output. Now when this spaced value is passed as parameter to `shell script` it breaks into 2 different values so:

These two parameter in script take 2 different values-:

```
repositoryName=$7
ddlimpschemalogPath=$8
```

**Output-:**

```
Siebel
repository
```

And it should be one value for parameter `repositoryName=$7` . Giving value `Siebel Repository`. Why is this happening? Can this me issue why value are up and down?

As you can see in `.bat` i am making call to shell script, and passing parameters taken from `.bat` file as below-:

```
DDL_Sync.sh %sadminUser% %sadminPassword% %dsnProvider% %dbUserName% %schemaFilePath% %ddldictschemalogPath% %repositoryName% %ddlimpschemalogPath% %grantUserRole% %datatable% %indexTable% %ddlimpschemalogPath2%"  > ddlSuccess.txt 2>&1
```

You can see complete line above in `.bat`.

Invoking `.bat` file -:

```
dlSync.bat "SAD" "glob81" "gepf_DSN" "SIEBEL" "/global/u70/globepfdev/siebel/schema.ddl" "/global/u70/globepfdev/siebel/siebsrvr/log/dev2prod/output/expschem.log" "Siebel Repository" "/global/u70/globepfdev/siebel/siebsrvr/log/dev2prod/output/ddlsync1.log" "SSE_ROLE" "GLOB_DATA_SMALL" "GLOB_INDEX_SMALL" "/global/u70/globepfdev/siebel/siebsrvr/log/dev2prod/output/ddlsync2.log"
```

Same parameter are passing out to shell script . where `"Siebel Repository"` breaks into 2. Thanks

Comment: please update your Q and remove the issue about $sadminUser, it's just distracting from your remaining problem. AND while the `.bat` file that creates the call is interesting, we need to see what an actual invocation of the shell script looks like. so please update with `./myShellscript.sh val1 val2 val3 ... val11`. It sounds like you have an unquoted space in your cmd invocation. Maybe you need `"\"Siebel Repository\""`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter hi i am updating the question.

Comment: good show! I've made several revisions to my comment. Be sure to refresh to read the whole thing. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter updated. let me know something else required.

Comment: @shellter as you mentioned use "\"Siebel Repository\"" . I tried and now echo  %repositoryName% gives -: "\"Siebel    as output, and also the last index value i was getting earlier is changed.I am not getting correct value again,and it's not even printing in shell script.But it does gives "Siebel repository" now.But also affected other values.

Comment: Ok, try `"Siebel\ Repository"` . If that doesn't work then a whole different approach in the shell script may be required. Search for `"$@"` examples. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter ok sir, I will try and update you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153035/discussion-between-shellter-and-tushar-sharma).

Comment: @shellter thanks sir it worked by using "Siebel\ Repository".